# Filter Powerpivot with VBA

Tags: excel, powerpivot, vba

OK, so this macro is supposed to loop through the pivot's SUPPLIER FILTER based on a list located in another worksheet. After every loop it has to upload the file to the intranet in a .pdf format.

The entire code is:

```
Sub Adinn()
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer

Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("List").Range("A:A")) - 1


ReDim SUPPLIER(n - 1, 1) As String

For i = 1 To n
SUPPLIER(i - 1, 0) = Worksheets("List").Cells(1 + i, 1)
SUPPLIER(i - 1, 1) = Worksheets("List").Cells(1 + i, 2)
Next i

For i = 1 To n
Sheets("To Supplier").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PageFields("[Query].[SUPPLIER].[SUPPLIER]").VisibleItemsList = _
"[Query].[SUPPLIER]." & SUPPLIER(i - 1, 0)

Sheets("To Supplier").Calculate

 Sheets("To Supplier").Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "http://enterpriseweb.com/portalone/sourcing/Supplier%20documents/" & SUPPLIER(i - 1, 1) _
    & "/Evaluations/" & SUPPLIER(i - 1, 1) & " Credits.pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
On Error Resume Next

Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Sheets("Overview").Select

End Sub
```

I think the issue is with both:

```
SUPPLIER(i - 1, 0) = Worksheets("List").Cells(1 + i, 1) 'Supplier Name
SUPPLIER(i - 1, 1) = Worksheets("List").Cells(1 + i, 2) 'Supplier Code
```

When I introduce them as PivotItem and concatenate it to the link.Obviously, what´s supposed to appear there is the value the represent.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to reference your `SUPPLIER` array in that line but you have included the array index in a string. Try this instead: `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PageFields("[Query].[SUPPLIER].[SUPPLIER]").CurrentPage = "[Query].[SUPPLIER]." & SUPPLIER(i - 1, 0)`

Comment: It still gives me run-time error '1004', unable to get the pagefields property of the pivottable class. :(

Comment: @nhee maybe you know what's going on?

Comment: Reads like it can't find `.VisibleItemsList` which points at `PageFields("[Query].[SUPPLIER].[SUPPLIER]")` not being found. Is that really what the field is called? Can you share the contents of the `SUPPLIER` array after you have filled it?

Comment: Yeah, thats the name... even when done manually.